# Supplying different configurations of the same type to different implementations?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have two implementations that each require a different set of configuration data *of the same type*:

```
public ConsumerA(Configuration config) : IConsumerA { ... }
public ConsumerB(Configuration config) : IConsumerB { ... }
```

In my installer, I have Windsor resolving the implementations:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IConsumerA>().ImplementedBy<ConsumerA>().LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<IConsumerB>().ImplementedBy<ConsumerB>().LifestyleTransient()
);
```

How can I ask Windsor to resolve the configurations based on the respective implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was naming the configurations and using a factory, sort of like so:

```
Component.For<IConsumerA>().ImplementedBy<ConsumerA>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(Configuration), "configurationA")).LifestyleTransient(),
Component.For<IConsumerB>().ImplementedBy<ConsumerB>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(Configuration), "configurationB")).LifestyleTransient(),

Component.For<Configuration>().UsingFactoryMethod(
   k => k.Resolve<ConfigurationFetcher>()
       .GetConfigurationSection<ConfigurationSection>(ConfigurationSection.ConfigurationASectionName)
       .GetConfiguration()).Named("configurationA"),
Component.For<Configuration>().UsingFactoryMethod(
   k => k.Resolve<ConfigurationFetcher>()
       .GetConfigurationSection<ConfigurationSection>(ConfigurationSection.ConfigurationBSectionName)
       .GetConfiguration()).Named("configurationB"),
```